# python tox: how to use a named env, with multiple versions?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, tox

I need to be able to call a tagged environment (due to a CICD setup that does not just call `tox` but rather `tox -e tag1,tag2,...`) but I want that env to use multiple python versions. I want something like this:

```
[tox]
envlist = mytag

[testenv:mytag]
deps=
    pytest
    coverage
    pytest-cov
python_versions = py37, py38 // I KNOW THIS IS NOT RIGHT

commands=
    pytest ...
```

The only way I would currently know how to do this is ugly as follows (calling `tox -e mytag37,mytag38` but this scales poorly as new versions are added)

```
[tox]
envlist = mytag37, mytag38

[testenv:mytag37]
basepython=python37 // see
deps=
    pytest
    coverage
    pytest-cov

commands=
    pytest ...


[testenv:mytag38]
basepython=python38 // see
deps=
    pytest
    coverage
    pytest-cov

commands=
    pytest ...
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: You can generate envs with bash expansion, e.g. `envlist = {py36,py37}-mytag` will generate you two environments, `py36-mytag` and `py37-mytag`. If you want to declare multiple interpreters for a single env, it's not possible - each env uses its own interpreter.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using the default `[testenv]` section, am I missing something?

Comment: can `testenv` be called with a tag like `-e something`? Stated otherwise please read the first sentence of my post. I thought `something` had to be a tag after a colon like `testenv:something`.

Comment: @hoefling it sounds like what you wrote achieves exactly what I need? Basically, the ability to generate the second block of code in my question from the first? If you post that as an answer I will try and accept!

Answer (score 1):

Use [substitution](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#substitution-for-values-from-other-sections):

```
[tox]
envlist = mytag37, mytag38

[mytag]
deps=
    pytest
    coverage
    pytest-cov
commands=
    pytest ...

[testenv:mytag37]
basepython=python37
deps={[mytag]deps}
commands={[mytag]commands}

[testenv:mytag38]
basepython=python38
deps={[mytag]deps}
commands={[mytag]commands}
```

Comment: oooooo nice solution, I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, maybe I am entirely missing the point of your question, but I believe what you are looking for is basically the default working mode of *tox*, so that something like the following should be enough:

```
[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
    coverage
    pytest-cov
commands =
    pytest ...
```

And call:

```
$ tox -e py36,py37,py38
```

Comment: what is the default behavior of `testenv` if you just call `tox`? What python version?

Comment: Have you tried it? I believe, if nothing is specified, then _tox_ just falls back to the Python interpreter that was used to start _tox_ in the first place, and it creates a virtual environment called `python`.